# Run function when screen under 1024px

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run the following function when screen width is equal or above 1024px

```
//Fade elements on Scroll
    var divs = $('.fader');
        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        divs.css({ 'opacity' : (1 - st/300) });
    });
```

I tried to add `if($(window).width() >= 1024){`

So its now looks like this:

```
var divs = $('.fader');
if($(window).width() >= 1024){
        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        divs.css({ 'opacity' : (1 - st/300) });
    });
    }
```

But it did not work, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but you can try. I think You have use `resize` event

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    var divs = $('.fader');
    if ($(window).width() >= 1024) {
        $(window).on('scroll', function () {
            var st = $(this).scrollTop();
            divs.css({
                'opacity': (1 - st / 300)
            });
        });
    } else {
        $(window).off('scroll');
    }
}).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: It worked thanks, if I want to apply it to more than one function, do I wrap it around them all?